# I am trying to run a CNN-LSTM model on a series of images with dimensions (9219, 7, 7, 12) but I get the following error in fit model

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2] * train_x.shape[3])))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 8, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 8, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))

from keras.optimizers import Adam

# change the optimizer,loss function
# and metrics according to your need

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(train_x.shape[1], train_y, epochs=20)
```

And I get this error

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=20)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
16                 except:
17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 7, 84), found shape=(None, 7, 7, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

As you mentioned, you have a dataset with a shape of `(9219, 7, 7, 12)`. The value 9219 represents the batch size, and from now on, I will use None to denote it.

So, the input data shape for the model should be `(None, 7, 7, 12)`. However, in the following line of your code:

```py
model.add(Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', 
    input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2] * train_x.shape[3])))
```

You've defined the model's input shape as `(None, 7, 84)`, which is incompatible and causes an exception.

Instead, you should use the following (I believe there was a typo in your code):

```py
model.add(Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', 
    input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_x.shape[3])))
```